# Botão delete deixa de funcionar

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho dois botões na minha tabela, o botão de editar e de delete:

```
<td><button type="button" name="edit" id="<?php echo $produto2["Id"]; ?>" data-target="#add_data_Modal2" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit_data2" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td>
<td><button type="button" id="<?php echo $produto2["Id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-dander btn-sm delete2" onsubmit="remove(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></td>
```

Com o botão editar chamo o modal que tem o botão gravar, como mostro no código:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="inserir_registo2();">Gravar</button>
```

O problema é se abrir o modal e voltar a fechar sem clicar no botão de gravar o botão delete funciona correctamente. Mas a partir do momento que abro o modal para editar e clico no botão gravar, o botão delete não funciona mais até atualizar a página.

Deixo aqui a função inserir_registo:

```
function inserir_registo2()
{  

    var dadosajax = {
        'Id' : $("#Id2").val(),
        'DataTermino' : $("#DataTermino").val(),
        'Tratamento' : $("#Tratamento").val(),
        'Estado' : $("#Estado2").val(),
        'Prestador' : $("#Prestador").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: './resolucaomanutencao',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: dadosajax,
        error: function(){
          $(".error_message").removeClass('hide');
        },
        success: function(result)
        { 
        $("#add_data_Modal2").modal("hide");
        $("#spoiler2").load(" #spoiler2 > *");
        }   
    });
}
```

função delete:

```
 remove = function(item) {

    var tr = $(item).closest('tr');

    tr.fadeOut(400, function() {
      tr.remove();  
    });

    return false;
  }

$(".delete2").click(function(){
        var id = this.id;
        if(confirm('Tem certeza de que deseja excluir a requisição?'))
        {
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "./deleterequisicao2", 
            type: "get",
            cache: false,           
            data: {id: id}, 
        error: function() {
                  alert('Algo está errado!');
               },
        success: function(data) {

                    $("#"+id).remove();
                    alert("Requisição removida com sucesso");
                    $("#spoiler2").load(" #spoiler2 > *");          
               }           
});

        }
});
```

Função do botão editar:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_data2', function(){  
           var employee_id2 = $(this).attr("Id");          
           $.ajax({  
                url:"./editarmanutencao",  
                method:"POST",
                cache: false,               
                data:{employee_id2:employee_id2},               
                dataType:"json",  
                success:function(data){

                    console.log(data);
                     $('#Id2').val(data.Id);
                     $('#Tratamento').val(data.Tratamento);
                     $('#Estado2').val(data.Estado);
                     $('#Prestador').val(data.Prestador);
                     $('#employee_id2').val(data.Id);                    
                     $('#insert2').val("Gravar");  
                     $("#add_data_Modal2").modal("show");                    
                }  
           });

      });
```

Comment: E cadê a função `function remove(data) { ... }` ?

Comment: @Ivan Ferrer já atualizei a pergunta com a função delete

Comment: você está usando modal: onsubmit, acho que é onclick, se vc usar onsubmit, vai submeter o form...

Comment: @Ivan Ferrer Mas se colocar onclick, se fizer cancelar retira a linha da tabela e não devia

Comment: em vez de colocar onclick ou onsubmit, deixe vazio, e chama o método remove() no retorno da ação de `$(".delete2")`

Comment: Os `ids` estão dobrados ambos os botões na função `inserir_registo2` recebem `id="${ item.Id }"`.

Comment: `... success: function(data) {
        
                    var _self = $("#"+id);
                    
                    remove(_self);` e remove isso do botão: `onsubmit="remove(this)"`

Comment: Na questão de ID dobrado, é so concatenar né com uma string diferente para cada caso...  `'id_add_' + id` e `'id_rm_'+ id`

Comment: `$("#id_rm_"+id).remove();` ID duplicada sempre vai dar erro.

Comment: @Ivan Ferrer não entendi a parte de concatenar os ids dobrados. Onde aplico essa situação?

Comment: @Ivan Ferre mesmo retirando a parte do código dos dois botões dentro da função inserir_registo2 para evitar os ids dobrados, o botão delete não funciona depois de editar e gravar uma linha na tabela. Editei a pergunta retirando essa parte do código

Comment: Que parte vc não entendeu de concatenar? Você não pode ter id duplicada, o jquery não encontra o elemento se vc tiver id duplicada, vc pode pegar o valor da sua id e duplicar ela desde que vc concatene com uma string diferente para cada caso, eu dei um exemplo para vc entender, vc sabe que o php retornará uma string inteira né da sua id, exemplo: `id="meuproduto_<?php echo $produto2["Id"]; ?>"` ficará: `id="meuproduto_1"`... daí vc usa essa string como ID, dessa string `meuproduto_` é onde vc irá variar.

Comment: @Ivan Ferrer, mas depois esse id fica diferente ao da id da base de dados, não vai criar problemas tanto ao fazer delete como ao fazer o update?

Comment: @Ivan Ferrer pode colocar como resposta o código com as alterações? Estou a tentar aplicar tudo o que foi sugerido nos comentários e continuo a ter sempre o mesmo problema, o botão deixa de funcionar.

Comment: Eu vou tentar dar uma resposta, apenas para esclarecer o que estou dizendo, mas fazer funcionar, precisaria do escopo integral do seu código.

Comment: @Sam podemos falar no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98192/discussion-between-bruno-and-sam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao usar AJAX, sempre use a forma delegada dos eventos.

Em vez de usar:

```
$(".delete2").click(function(){
```

Use:

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete2", function(){
```

O objeto `document` é sempre atualizado. Informações sobre o método `.on()` você encontra na documentação oficial do jQuery -> https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 6):

1) Mude no seus botões:

Editar (que abre o modal):

```
<button type="button" name="edit" data-id="<?php echo $produto2["Id"]; ?>" id="open_<?php echo $produto2["Id"]; ?>" data-target="#add_data_Modal2" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit_data2" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
```

Deletar:

```
<button type="button" data-id="<?php echo $produto2["Id"]; ?>" id="delete_<?php echo $produto2["Id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-dander btn-sm delete2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
```

Na sua `<tr>` que é o container do elemento listado, acrescente:

`data-itemid="<?php echo $produto2["Id"]; ?>"`

2) no JavaScript:

```
$(".delete2").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $el = $("tr [data-itemid]");  
        if (confirm('Tem certeza de que deseja excluir a requisição?')) {
            $.ajax({ 
                url: "./deleterequisicao2", 
                type: "get",
                cache: false,           
                data: {id: id}, 
                error: function() {
                    alert('Algo está errado!');
                },
                success: function(data) {

                     $el.fadeOut(400, function() {
                         $el.remove();  
                         alert("Requisição removida com sucesso");
                         $("#spoiler2").load(" #spoiler2 > *");      
                     });

               }           
          });

       }
});
```

Comment: descobri qual era o problema e era por causa desta linha: `$("#spoiler2").load(" #spoiler2 > *");`, isto é que faz com que o id se repeti, como posso fazer o mesmo sem acontecer isso?

Comment: Fazendo exatamente como eu falei, use classe ao invés de ID.

Comment: Embora esta seja a solução, poderia ser melhorada se explicasse a causa do problema e depois sim, oferecesse a solução.

Comment: E pra que vc precisa fazer esse carregamento? `$("#spoiler2").load(" #spoiler2 > *");` no seu código não está especificado.